# What is Pipeline of the sckit-learn?

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn

I'm studying sckit-learn. but I cant understand the proper process of Pipeline. Here's the example like followng;

[image]

It's my studying material. How the Pipeline works here?

Comment: Please do not take photos of code - insert the ode directly into the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pipeline allowed you to perform multiple steps by connecting them as a pipeline.

In your case, you first generated feature vectors from the TfidfVectorizer(), and then those are "piped" to the naive bayes classifier as training data.